# How is it possible that there is no such $n$ that would make $A$ isolated?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am reading [this paper](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v30/tp30120.pdf) on Atsuji metric space. *A metric space $X$ is said to be **Atsuji** if every real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.*

In theorem 3.7 , it is proved that **[see 3.7(e)]**, *if $X$ is an Atsuji space then for any real-valued continuous function $f$ on $X$, there is some natural number $n$ such that every point of $A=\{x:|f(x)|\ge n\}$ is isolated and $\inf\{I(x):x\in A\}>0.$*

> Now $[0,1]$ is an Atsuji space (being compact) and $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto0.5$ is continuous. But I cannot find any $n$ such that $A=\{x:|f(x)|\ge n\}$ is isolated. How is it possible that there is no such $n$ that would make $A$ isolated?

Comment: Take $n=1$, in this case $A = \emptyset$ which is trivially isolated and $\inf \{I (x) : x \in A\} = \infty > 0$

Comment: @Youem Can't we consider $\emptyset$ to be a set where every point is an accumulation point?

Comment: I think you can. Because when you have an logic assertion $\mathcal P (x)$, then the assertion $\mathcal Q : \{\forall x \in \emptyset, \, \mathcal P(x) \text{ is true}\}$ is always true.

Comment: okay. Thanks so much.